# Custom data grid template column check box isn't binding to object when DatagridCheckboxColumn is correctly binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a custom column I am trying to make in WPF.

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
            <CheckBox x:Name="checkAll" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked"></CheckBox>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
           <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="#" Binding="{Binding userFriendlyId}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Log Number" Binding="{Binding logNumber}" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Both of the `DataGridTextColumns` are correctly bound to properties of my object and if I swap out my custom column for a `DataGridCheckboxColumn` it binds properly. I am trying to use this column because I want to have a check all/uncheck all option for the datagrid. Also it only takes one click to trigger these checkboxes as opposed to using the `DataGridCheckboxColumn`.

I use this code to asssign the ItemSource of the data grid:

```
DataGrid.ItemsSource = samples;
DataGrid.Items.Refresh();
```

I also currently have `this.DataContext = this;` although that doesn't seem to be making any sort of difference.

EDIT: Data Model that is displaying in the grid:

```
public class Sample
{
    public bool isSelected { get; set; }
    public int userFriendlyId { get; set; }
    public string logNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to include the code for the DataModel displayed in the grid?

Comment: @Rachel I added in the DataModel I think?

Comment: try setting your binding to `IsChecked="{Binding isSelected}"`. The property names in the bindings are case-sensitive so if your object model is `isSelected` than your binding should be as well

Comment: @Rachel !!!!! I think that did it. UH stupid casing :( thanks so much !

Comment: Glad that worked out for you :) I posted that as an answer below (I didn't before because frequently something like that is a typo and not related to the question - wanted to verify first)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your binding to `IsChecked="{Binding isSelected}"`

The property names in bindings are case-sensitive so if your object model uses `isSelected` than your binding should be as well.